# MongoDB/C# and Telerik Ajax RadGrid

Tags: c#, mongodb, telerik, telerik-grid, mongodb-.net-driver

Can some expert propose a way to use Telerik RadControls Ajax Grids and MongoDb C# Official driver to manage a simple Grid table Create/Update/Delete methods. The object is managing a simple Table data from a web control.

- What are the best object to use : BsonObjects, List, DataTables
- Best ways client or server side

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use FindAs to load some collection from database(probably you will also use skip, limit, and SetSor tOrder).
2. I am not familiar with telerik-grid at all but it seems to me that as usual grid, telerik grid has some property like DataSource. So you can bind data using DataSource property.
3. For the update/delete/insert methods i suppose telerik grid has some kind of events(like on item insert, delete). And you can easy create methods thats will be update/delete/insert in mongo.

In abstract process will looks like:

```
var items = mongoCollection.FindAs<Type>(Query.EQ("someProperty", "someValue"))
           .SetSortOrder("orderField").SetLimit(100).Skip(10);

telerikGrid.DataSource = items;
telerikGrid.DataBind();

....

telerikGrid_OnItemDelete(object sender, SomeEventArgs e)
{
   var id = e. //get parameter from args
   ..
   mongoCollection.Remove(Query.EQ("_id", id));
}
```

Also i suggest you ask question about telerik grid( How to bind list of data to telerik grid?), or take a look into telerik documentation (i suppose that telerik has perfect documentation). Or even ask telerik community.

Hope my 'abstract' answer somehow help you.

Comment: +1, working with the Telerik grid isn't substantially divergent from the standard gridview control and you could program for it the same way nearly. With loading the grid you want to create an OnNeedDataSource event that calls the binding to the grid (you won't need to call .Databind on the grid if you bind in this method) One nice advantage to using that event is you can reload the data at any point by just calling `grid.Rebind()` (useful for after updates etc). As Bugai said you just need to wire up all the events for CRUD which is a PITA sadly.